# Changing the background color of a cell using a class

Tags: html, css, class

```
<html>
<font face = "arial">
<style>
#periodictable {
   position: static;
   border-top: : solid red 1pt;
   border-right:solid red 1pt;
   border-bottom:solid red 1pt;
   border-left:solid red 1pt;
}
.metalloid {
   background-color : #AF9B60;
}
.metal {
   background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
</style>
<body>
<table width = "202" height = "211">
<div id = "periodictable";>
 <tr>
  <td bgcolor = #AF9B60><div class = "metalloid"><center>B</center></div></td>
  <td><center>C</center></td>
  <td><center>N</center></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><div class = "metal"><center>Al</center></div></td>
  <td bgcolor = #AF9B60><div class = "metalloid"><center>Si</center></div></td>
  <td><center>P</center></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><div class = "metal"><center>Ga</center></div></td>
  <td><div class = "metalloid"><center>Ge</center></div></td>
  <td><div class = "metalloid"><center>As</center></div></td>
 </tr>
</div>
</table>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

So, basically for my highschool HTML/CSS class, I had to create a table using CSS. With the assignment it is required to use classes and id's. With my code, i had assigned the class and called it using a div statement. But when doing so, only the text's background is changed to the color i assigned. I need for the whole cell block to be changed as shown in the following image:

[image: sample]

Comment: 1) What DID you apply the class to, and what are its contents? 
2) What HTML element is the "cell block" you actually want to affect, and did you assign a class to it? 

If you can answer these questions, you'll fix your problem.

Comment: [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) and [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) elements are deprecated/obsolete; the [`bgcolor`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#adef-bgcolor) attribute likewise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the `<td>` a class, and then change it's `background-color` attribute, the `<div>` is only as big as your css defines or the elements within - not the parent element.

eg..

```
.metal {
    text-align: center;
    background: silver;
}
```

..

```
<tr>
    <td class="metal">Ga</td>
</tr>
```

Since this is basically answering your homework, please try and understand for yourself why this works.